# I Can't Reach A DB Using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm following a tutorial that is teaching PDO but I'm stuck at a very early point.

Referring to the code below I have diagnosed the problem down to the DB selected.

When I run print_r($query); there is no output and initallally I thought the problem was that the script wasn't connecting to the MySql server at all but then I learned if I change anything in host, user or pass I get an error message, but no matter what I change related to the database nothing happens and no error messages are displayed.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'xxxx',
    'user'      => 'xxxx',
    'pass'      => 'xxxx',
    'database'  => 'xxxx'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';database=' . $config['db']['database'],$config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass']);
$query = $db->query("SELECT `subscribers`.`first_name` FROM `subscribers`");

print_r($query);


echo 'Anything';

?>
```

If anyone could show me what Im doing wrong I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

BTW, I am SURE that SELECT `subscribers`.`first_name` FROM `subscribers` is correct as this works when I insert it into the mysql tab within php MyAdmin

Comment: does `Anything` get displayed?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? What do `var_dump($db->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($query->ErrorInfo())` print out?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, Anything is outputted.

Comment: @andrewsi The pieces of code you provided I have no experience with

Comment: Allow me to Add: Using the xxxx for the paramaters, (I can't reveal the actual data for obvious reasons) Anyways... When I run this I get the following:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'xxxx' (1)' in /xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx/.php(11): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=xxxx...', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') #1 {main} thrown in /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.php on line xx

Comment: Please note I changed the dir structure to xxxxx but what I have noticed is that PDO->__construct('mysql:host=xxxx...', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')  doesn't have enough params and this is not modified by me and my x's but I also have no idea how to correct this

Comment: are you still using `database=` instead of `dbname=`?

Comment: @dbf I am using dbname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the DSN parameter for database name is called `dbname`, not `database`.

Try this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['database'],$config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass']);
```

Comment: Wow!! That might do it. Thanks @Martin Cernac

Comment: That Did It!! You're a Genius!! I made that change during the turorial so I could understand it better. I never knew that was a preset variable. Huge Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

After creating a connection with database you need to create a statement, set query, bind values(optional), execute the query and fetch the result. In your case:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';database=' . $config['db']      ['database'],$config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass']);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `subscribers`.`first_name` FROM `subscribers`");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```